# Make Unity run in 3D mode on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, samsung, 3d

My computer, a Samsung q330 with a Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz with 4 GB RAM, runs Unity in 2D mode. I have tried to see how to activate 3D mode, but I cant figure out how to do it and I am in doubt whether or not my laptop acually has the power to run it in 3D mode.
Can you help me find out about that?

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci` to the question. That will show the graphics hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it work with open graphic drivers cause every time I had 2d mode was when i had graphic driver errors

### ATi:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

### Nvidia:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

To purge it if having problems use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>f1</kbd> to summon console and install [ppa-purge [image: Install ppa-purge]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ppa-purge):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then use the newly installed `ppa-purge` command to purge the package:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Or install closed drivers go to dash and search drivers and activate driver.

Other option is to download your video card driver from ATi, Nvidia and find instructions to install it.

Comment: I tried the first option you gave me, rebotted, and it didn't make it run 3D.. The second option you are giving me im not quiet sure of. I have a "nvidea_experimental_310" driver, but it says "This driver is activated but currently not in use". Will it help if I make it go to use, and if that so, how do I make it come to use?

Comment: i edited the main comment as it more customizable and easier to understand